# is there a Typescript external module reference available inside the module?

Tags: typescript, amd

In javascript, when I define an AMD module I create and return a reference to the exposed portions of the module.  When I use Typescript, I 'export' items, which causes them to be added to the 'exports' variable.

```
//javascript module
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    exports.message = function(s) {
        console.log(s);
    }
}
```

In Typescript, I would like to get a reference to the external module from within the module, while it's being defined.  Basically, I'd like access to the generated 'exports' variable, but can't find a way.
Among other reasons, I'd like to be able to call Duradal's system.getModuleId and pass the current module.

Thanks

Comment: Given that TypeScript is - for all intents and purposes - JavaScript, ask yourself how you would do this in JavaScript. If you cannot do it in JS, you cannot do it in TS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare var exports;

export var n = 4;
console.log(exports);
```

Produces:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    exports.n = 4;
    console.log(exports);
});
```